# if statement not working to add 1 based on a condition

Tags: java

This code determines the wins and losses of each quarter but I am having trouble with the PerfectQuarter. A PerfectQuarter is described as when one team has 0 points in a quarter but the other team scores.
Everything runs fine but when I enter scores for each quarter and put  00-01 for quarter one, the print statement at the end of my program prints

> PerfectQuarters: 0

for both teams, although Team 2 should have a perfect quarter of 1 since in QuarterOne they scored once and Team 1 scored 0 points.

```
         if (teamOneQuarterOne > teamTwoQuarterOne) {
         teamOneStats += "W-";
         teamTwoStats += "L-";

         if (teamOneQuarterOne == 0 && teamTwoQuarterOne > 0) {
             teamTwoPerfectQuarter++;        }
     } else if (teamTwoQuarterOne < teamOneQuarterOne) {
         teamOneStats += "L-";
         teamTwoStats += "W-";

         if (teamTwoQuarterOne == 0 && teamOneQuarterOne > 0) {
             teamOnePerfectQuarter++;   }
     } else if (teamOneQuarterOne < teamTwoQuarterOne) {
         teamOneStats += "L-";
         teamTwoStats += "W-";

     } else {
         teamOneStats += "T-";
         teamTwoStats += "T-";        }

System.out.println(teamOne + " Perfect Quarters: " + teamOnePerfectQuarter);
     System.out.println(teamTwo  + " Perfect Quarters: " +  teamTwoPerfectQuarter);
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly and make it a runnable example.

Comment: An easier trick to do this is using subtraction, `teamOneQuarterOne - teamTwoQuarterOne` if the result is positive then team1 wins, if negative team2 wins, if zero then they are both equal. you can play around with booleans to check perfect quarter by adding either 1 or 0 to both values `teamOnePerfectQuarter += teamTowQuarterOne == 0 ? 1 : 0;` and `teamTowPerfectQuarter += teamOneQuarterOne == 0 ? 1 : 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to divide "comparing" conditions and "check perfect" conditions in two separate if-else branches

```
class Example {
  public void main(String[] args) {
    if (teamOneQuarterOne > teamTwoQuarterOne) {
      teamOneStats += "W-";
      teamTwoStats += "L-";
    } else if (teamOneQuarterOne < teamTwoQuarterOne) {
      teamOneStats += "L-";
      teamTwoStats += "W-";
    } else {
      teamOneStats += "T-";
      teamTwoStats += "T-";
    }

    if (teamOneQuarterOne == 0 && teamTwoQuarterOne > 0) {
      teamTwoPerfectQuarter++;
    } else if (teamTwoQuarterOne == 0 && teamOneQuarterOne > 0) {
      teamOnePerfectQuarter++;
    }
    System.out.println(teamOne + " Perfect Quarters: " + teamOnePerfectQuarter);
    System.out.println(teamTwo + " Perfect Quarters: " + teamTwoPerfectQuarter);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you expect these lines to increase the perfect count.

```java
if (teamOneQuarterOne == 0 && teamTwoQuarterOne > 0) {
             teamTwoPerfectQuarter++;        }
```

But these lines are only relevant if the enveloping condition is true

```java
if (teamOneQuarterOne > teamTwoQuarterOne)
```

But both cannot be true together at the same time.

It seems that you have misplaced those lines, I'd expect them in here:

```java
if (teamOneQuarterOne < teamTwoQuarterOne) {
         teamOneStats += "L-";
         teamTwoStats += "W-";
         /* here */
     }
```